# Were the ancient Hebrews basically an African tribe?

Tags: jews, africa, israel, anthropology, hebrew

[Hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_language) is one of the earliest [Afroasiatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afroasiatic_languages) languages. It has been argued that the Hebrews were an offshoot of the Canaanites, even akin to them. It is nearly undisputable that the Canaanites were Africanoid people  in both language and appearance. The geographical location of the time determines the Canaanites and Hamitic peoples to be Africanoid. With the early Hebrews originating from such a group and being so closely intertwined with these Africanoid peoples, would it be too far-fetched to say that the early Hebrews were presumably an African tribe and or Africanoid in language and appearance?

Taking in mind the geographic location, the peoples in that area at that time and that Hebrew is one of the early Afroasiatic languages.

Comment: @Comintern, indeed, Im more looking at the question from a linguistic and geographic perspective, I felt that it could be deduced better that way.